# How to customize the react navigation back button with nested stack navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

Here is my navigators stack:

```
Root [SwitchNavigator (default: Auth)]
|
|--- Auth: AuthScreen
|
|--- Authentified [BottomTabNavigator (default: Devices)]
|
|------ Devices [StackNavigator (default: Home)]
|
|--------- Home: DevicesScreen
|
|--------- Device: DeviceDetails
|
|------ Places [StackNavigator (default: Home)]
|
|--------- Home: PlacesScreen
|
|--------- Place: PlaceDetails
|
|------ Profile [StackNavigator (default: Home)]
|
|--------- Home: ProfileScreen
```

**Context:** The view `DevicesScreen` render a list of item. If you press one of them, you will navigate to the Device view (DeviceDetails component), in order to see more about the device. In this details view, you will see the device's place. You can press it and will navigate to the view Place (PlaceDetails component). The PlaceDetails view have a list of devices. You can press one in order to navigate to the Device (DeviceDetails view).

**Problem:** When I am in a details view, I can use the back button (headerLeft). But, if I am on a device details, and I navigate to a place details, then I press the back button, I go to the default Places route, so the list of places... That's logic because stack navigators are differents. But the expected behaviour as a user would be to come back on device details view. (The converse is also valid).

I tried to set a more global stack navigator, grouping Devices, Places and Profile routes, but it causes side effects (if I only navigate from Devices list to Places list with the TabBar, I will have a back button in the header...).

**Question:** Is it possible to have the expected behaviour like a user will expect?

Thanks in advance.